# Backbone event get element type

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, underscore.js

I have a backbone.js app that has a view called StoreProductView.js:

```
var StoreProductView = Backbone.View.extend({
  events: {
    "click .changeProductType"          : "changeProductType"
  },
  render: function () {

    this.$el.append(render("products/product"));
  },
  changeProductType: function (e) {
    console.debug(e.currentTarget.parentNode.next("li"));
  }
});
```

When I call `console.debug(e.currentTarget.parentNode)`, it returns:

```
<li>
  <a class='changeProductType' data-type="book">Book</a>
</li>
```

I'm trying to get it to return "book" from the data-type, but with my current code I'm getting the error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function
```

Comment: why don't you include the current code that is erroring?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DOM `HTMLElement` object doesn't have `.next()` method, you are probably trying to call the jQuery `.next()` method on a non-jQuery object, if you want to get the next element of a raw DOM element you should read the [`nextElementSibling`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ChildNode.nextElementSibling) property.

If you want to call the jQuery `.next()` method you should at first create a jQuery object:

```
$(event.currentTarget).parent().next('li');
```

And for reading the `data-*` attribute you can use the jQuery `.data()` method:

```
$matchedElement.find('a').data('type');
```

That being said since the `currentTarget` property refers to the clicked element you don't need the `.next()` method:

```
$(event.currentTarget).data('type');
```